# var_dump HEX string gives me �? pack function error

Tags: php, hex

I'm trying to run:

```
pack("H*", $data);
```

but im getting an error pack() type h illegal hex digit.

So I ran:

```
var_dump($data);
```

It gives me a hex like: 202020202020202020202020202020202020200D0A787265660D0A362034310D�0A303030

however when I do:

```
echo $data
```

it will give me an result of

202020202020202020202020202020202020200D0A787265660D0A362034310D0A303030

Im almost positive the question mark is causing the pack function to fail.  How can I get rid of it?  Is it some encoding issue?

Here is the code I am using:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT top 1 Data FROM c04_docs");
//Data column is BLOB that contains the HEX string
$sth->execute();
$res = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data = $res[0]['Data'];
```

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that you only get the string with: `var_dump($data);` Please add the full output of it

Comment: Updated Rizier123, the hex string usually contains a high amount of characters (50000 - 70000)

Comment: I wrote a hexdump lib for that purpose: https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump .. Can you try it an post the output?